# Meteor.js , Image data for input file for upload via Ajax?

Tags: ajax, meteor, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have Image data from Meteor `getPicture()`. And I have form which I want to send via Ajax (Jquery AjaxForm plugin actually) as simple multipart form data with file (that image) but look like a pain, I've lost whole day searching for good solution.

I've also tried simplier way:
`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"  capture="camera">`

But no luck so far :/

**Background**: Some local Public service has Web Form, but I'm really trying to make an App, because their idea is to post problems about problems on locality... but who wanna save image and post it via PC,right? So i'm writing this Little App which will post from-the-sight an problem report.
Idea is to post simple form like you post from PC, but in this case, an file input should be able to capture via camera and later send after filling other necesseary fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this package to save your images to the Mongo DB. You can add meta data to the images if you want to save your form data as well. Alternatively you can store your form data in a separate collection and store the _id of the photo with the form data.

https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection

Here is a small meteor app for taking photos, but you probably have that already

https://github.com/mikkelking/cheese-test